Angular - HttpErrorResponse
I have an application that uses Angular 12, and I have my interceptor file, where I do error handling, and/or display a dialog with a message or do other handling, however, in this particular situation, I need that when it gets error 400, the data that comes from back, are received in my component method in the error() part;
Below is my interceptor file.
@Injectable()
export class Authintercept implements HttpInterceptor {

  errorMessage$: any;
  showError$: any;
  private API = `${environment.BaseUrl}`;


  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private authservice: AuthService,
    private utilService: UtilService
  ) { }



  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

    this.errorMessage$ = this.authservice.errorMessage$;
    this.showError$ = this.authservice.showError$;

    if (this.authservice.hasToken()) {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-parameter-reassignment
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers
          .set('Authorization', `bearer ${this.authservice.getToken()}`)
          .set('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; media-src 'self';") 
          .set('Feature-Policy', 'fullscreen=(), autoplay=()') 
          .set('Permissions-Policy', 'camera=(), geolocation=(), microphone=()') 
          .set('X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies', 'none') 
          .set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest') 
          .set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache') 
          .set('X-Frame-Options', 'DANY')
          .set('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block')
          .set('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
          .set('Referrer-Policy', 'no-referrer')
          .set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains') 
          .set('X-CSRF-Token', 'csrfToken') 
      });
      next.handle(request);
    }

    if (request.method === 'POST' && request.url.includes(`${this.API}/projeto/gerarDados`)) {
      return next.handle(request);
    } else {
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            } else {
              switch (error.status) {
                case 0:
                  this.mensagem('Não foi possível se conectar ao servidor.');
                  break;
                case 400:
                  this.validacoes(error);
                  break;
                case 401:
                  this.mensagem('Ação proibida.');
                  break;
                case 403:
                  this.mensagem('Ocorreu um erro interno, contacte o helpdesk.');
                  break;
                case 404:
                  this.mensagem(`Registro não encontrado na base de dados.`);
                  break;
                case 405:
                  this.mensagem(error);
                  break;
                case 503:
                  this.mensagem('Ocorreu um erro interno, contacte o helpdesk.');
                  break;
                case 500:
                  this.validacoes(error);
                  break;
                default:
                  break;
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log('um error ocorreu');
          }
          return throwError(() => Error(error));
        })
      );
    }

  }

  private mensagem(mensagem: any) {
    this.dialog.open(DialogMessageComponent, {
      data: mensagem,
    });
    this.utilService.emiteErrorUploadCargaParqueManual.next(true);
  }

  private validacoes(error: any) {
    if (error.error.tipoErro) {
      if (error.error.tipoErro === null) {
        console.log('1');
        this.mensagem(`${error.error}`);
      } else {
        console.log('2');
        this.utilService.notificaErro.emit(error.error);
      }
    } else if (typeof error.error === 'string') {
      console.log('3');
      this.mensagem(`${error.error}`);
    } else if (error.error.mensagemErro) {
      console.log('4');
      sessionStorage.setItem('nomeArquivo', error.error.nomeArquivo);
      this.mensagem(error.error.mensagemErro);
    } else if (error.error.errors) {
      console.log('5');
      this.mensagem(JSON.stringify(error.error.errors));
    } else if (error.error instanceof Blob) {
      console.log('6');
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        const mensagem = reader.result;
        this.mensagem(mensagem);
      };
      reader.readAsText(error.error);
    } else if (error.error.success === false || error.error.success !== undefined) {
      console.log('7');
      this.showError$.next(true);
      this.errorMessage$.next(error.error.mensagem);
    } else {
      console.log('8');
      if (error.error) {
        console.log('9');
        console.log('===============================================');
        console.log(error);
        console.log('===============================================');
        console.log(error.error);
        this.mensagem(error.error);
        return;
      }
      this.mensagem('Não há nenhum registro ou ocorreu um erro interno.');
    }
  }

}

When my method gives an error, it falls to this part:
} else {
console.log('8');
      if (error.error) {
        console.log('9');
        console.log('===============================================');
        console.log(error);
        console.log('===============================================');
        console.log(error.error);
        this.mensagem(error.error);
        return;
      }
}

And my method is this:
salvar() {
    const valor = ({
      ...this.form.value,
      horaProximoDia: this.serviceCompartilhada.ajusteHora(this.form.value.horaProximoDia),
    })
    this.service.liberarProximoAtendimento(valor).subscribe({
      next: (res: any) => {
        this.dialogRef.close(res);
      },
      error: (err: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
        this.dialogRef.close(err);
      },
    });
  }

And always in my method no error : (), it only arrives this way below, without giving the possibility to handle it, even using HttpErrorResponse or HttpRespose, or Erroevent.
Error:  Error: [object Object]
    at authintercept.interceptor.ts:97:35
    at Observable.init [as _subscribe] (throwError.js:5:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:37:25)
    at Observable.js:31:30
    at errorContext (errorContext.js:19:9)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:22:21)
    at catchError.js:14:31
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:40:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.mjs:1828:30)

